# Convergence , conditional distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

here my short question.

I saw the following conditional distribution, which converges, in a book:

$\lim_{s \to \infty}P\left(\frac{X-f(s)}{g(s)}\leq x\mid X>s\right)=G(x)\ \forall x$ in the set of continuity points of G

with the informations, that $f(s)>0,g(s)$ functions in real numbers and $G(x)$ distribution function. $X$ is a random variable with known distribution function.

my question is: what type of convergence is it???

my problem: we don t have a sequence of random variables $X_{n}$, because $f,g$ are functions in real numbers, so i think we can`t work with the known convergences like "weak convergence" or is it possible??

thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Weak convergence in this context means convergence in distribution, and that's excatly what you've got.  Weak convergence to a c.d.f. $G$ means pointwise convergence to $G$ at all points at which $G$ is continuous.  It doesn't matter whether it's convergence of a sequence or convergence of a function of a real variable or convergence of some other kind of net.

Comment: okay, thanks,

i only know the following definition of weak convergence:

$\lim_{n \to \infty}F_{n}(x)=F(x)$ for all continuity points.

is there an other one which would used in the given case?

because when you say it is pointwise convergence i have the same problem: i only know a definition of pointwise convergence for sequences of functions like $f_{n}$ with n positive integer.

why doesn t it change anything, and why is there no Definition with real numbers it would be more general i think

Comment: Pointwise convergence just means convergence at each particular argument separately.  $\lim\limits_{s\to\infty} f_s$ pointwise means that for each value of $x$ we have $\lim\limits_{s\to\infty}f_s(x)$. And in the case of weak convergence of probability distributions, it means that happens for each value of $x$ at which the limiting function is continuous. ${}\quad{}$